# Amazon Cloudfront slower for delivering assets than serving them directly from EC2?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-experience, amazon-cloudfront

I've noticed that on mobile Safari, when I deliver my assets via Cloudfront they load noticeably slower than if my assets are served just from my EC2.

Specifically, my site has a main background image that appears noticeably slower than the text delivered by EC2. The loading of this background image doesn't noticeably lag behind the text on Chrome on my laptop presumably b/c of the greater performance of Chrome vs. mobile Safari.

I'm at a loss about what to do about this since the whole point of Cloudfront is to serve assets fast and take load of my EC2 but the delay in this background image appearing makes for quite an ugly, i.e., unacceptably bad, UX.

**NOTE:** *Please don't reflexively vote to migrate this question to another SE site as the whole point is that it is not clear what approach would be best.*

Comment: How large is the background image you are loading? What type of network are you connecting via with mobile safari.

Comment: @datasage the image is only 8kb. I'm using my iphone on comcast wifi while at home in a major US city though I've noticed this in many parts of the US on many different networks.

Comment: I doubt transfer speed is an issue here. The image should load pretty fast even on a noisy mobile connection. There may be an issue of when the request gets made. If its at the bottom of a large css file, it could take some time before mobile safari parses it and requests it.

Comment: Its at the top of the HTML but its in an inline `<style>` tag which should be faster than an external CSS file, right?. I realize this question is kinda vague but was just hoping for some brainstorming so thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that will be faster, you can skip the request for the css file. Are there any tools for profiling in mobile safari? I know android has usb debugging that can provide access to profiles via chrome dev tools.

Comment: yeah as of iOS6, you can connect your iPhone to Mac and profile it via the Mac Safari's developer tools. Have anything in mind I should be looking for? Not too familiar with profiling/peformance testing in the developer tools. Only mainly used it for checking CSS styling...

Comment: I would be looking to see if there is any delay on the requests. Then trying to trace back to what might be blocking it, if its starting late, or trying to determine if there are network issues if its loading slowly.

Answer (score 3):

We've done some comparative tests and it seems that the advantage of using cloudfront depends on the size of the requested file.
For a small file (2kb) CF response time is greater than requesting directly to EC2.
For a 15kb file the response time is almost the same.
For a 57kb file (jquery-1.3.2.min.js), cloudfront was 4x to 5x faster than EC2.